# Call requires API level 26 while using Java 8+ API desugaring support

Tags: java, android, kotlin, jdk-desugaring

I'm testing [Java 8+ API desugaring support](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) on a project with minSdk 23.

When I use the `java.time` library, for example `val instant = Instant.now()`, I get the following error:

> Call requires API level 26 (current min is 23): java.time.Instant#now

The code compiles and executes correctly.

Can I assume it will work for all devices?

EDIT:
I've tried with API 29 (physical device) and API 23 (emulator).

Comment: On which version of android you have tested ? as the warning says it will work only on 26 and above on below it will crash .

Comment: @ADM api levels 29 and 23.

Comment: Well by looking at the docs it seems its independent of minimum API version with only gradle plugin 4.0.0 and above. If you use 4 and above then it should work . Also pls read the documentation  carefully cause i see there is only a Sub set is available for some APIs.. And yeah i am not sure how this warning will go away ..